# Listener.ora problem when I copy OVA

Tags: oracle

I deployed a new VM Oracle machine using a copy of my existing Oracle VM. As a result, the new VM inherited the same host name.  This is redhat linux 6.5, Oracle11g. I changed hostname everywhere as far as I know. However, when I start the listener, it still points to old host name!

I can not find listener.ora under the usual $../network/admin.  I created one but still it ignores it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to update /etc/hosts to map the local IP with the new hostname.